# Would this correspond to a spinor space?

Tags: spinors

Take a 2D manifold and thicken it by adding a 3rd dimension of radius $4\pi$.

Now we define fields on this $\psi(x,y,z) = \psi(x,y,z+4\pi)$

Then we say the physics is invariant under the following transformations of these fields:

A translation $$\psi(x,y,z)\rightarrow \psi(x+a,y+b,z)$$

And an 'augmented' rotation:

$$\psi(x,y,z)\rightarrow \psi(x\cos(\theta)+y\sin(\theta),y\cos(\theta)-x\sin(\theta),z+\theta)$$

which if you ignore the 3rd dimension this is a rotation but it does not fully go back to itself until a 720 degree rotation.

So that seems to be a lot like the definition of a spinor if we say that $\psi(x,y,z)$ and $\psi(x,y,z+2\pi)$ both represent the same physics.

Therefor could a spinor be represented in terms of curled up dimensions, in which the symmetry group is not simply the rotation group on the uncompact dimensions, but a mixed symmetry which appears as a rotation on the uncompact dimensions together with a translation in the compact dimensions?

In other words, can spinors in D dimensional space be represented as transformations in D+N dimensonal space without using superspace?

The symmetry group of the translation+augmented rotation does seem to close. And I it does seem to generalise to higher dimensions.

I suppose another way to put this is if there is a representation of the group Spin(D) in terms of differential transformations in some dimension D+N.

Comment: Zooby, while I don't follow your maths (why make a rolled-up dimension's *radius* be a multiple of π; that seems rather arbitrary) I've long wondered whether the "internal degree of freedom" of quantum spin (but not the 'direction' of a spinor) might simply be an 'Uncertainty-driven' rotation around a rolled-up dimension...

Comment: @iSeeker it just makes the math easier.